# How to write in protractor with same elements for different Text Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

For the text boxes Inspect Element values are same for Three text boxes with different divs and tag names.

```
      <div class="input-group-addon ng-binding">NAME</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-class="{error:hasError(k)}" id="name" name="name" ng-model="row[k]" placeholder="0" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" style="">


      <div class="input-group-addon ng-binding">SEQUENCE_NUM</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-class="{error:hasError(k)}" id="name" name="name" ng-model="row[k]" placeholder="0" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" style="">


      <div class="input-group-addon ng-binding">VALUE</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-class="{error:hasError(k)}" id="name" name="name" ng-model="row[k]" placeholder="0" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" style="">
```

The xpaths for name, sequence_num and values are same //*[@id="name"]. 
The css xpaths for name, sequence_num and values are same #name
The css selector for name, sequence_num and values are same  .ng-touched

And it is difficult to enter values from automation.

How do I write in Protractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is you specify text in locators:
For xpath: `//div[text()="NAME"]/following-sibling::input[@id="name"]`, `//div[text()="SEQUENCE_NUM"]/following-sibling::input[@id="name"]`, `//div[text()="VALUE"]/following-sibling::input[@id="name"]`

The right way is like this

```
let myLocator = label => '//div[text()="' + label + '"]/following-sibling::input[@id="name"]';

let $nameInput = element(by.xpath(myLocator("NAME")));
let $sequenceNum = element(by.xpath(myLocator("SEQUENCE_NUM")));
let $valueInput = element(by.xpath(myLocator("VALUE")));
```

Comment: be careful with xpath, since the text is case sensitive and should exactly match. Both can be got around, but locator will be different. Just FYI